# What are the most active community resources for MFC development?

Tags: mfc

I am wondering what are the best community resources for MFC development- such as forums, IRC channels, etc.  Currently the only resource I have for finding answered questions on MFC is using google which comes up with Codeproject results or the occasional result on MSDN or some other web page.  Now that there is stackoverflow I am sure I will be asking more questions here, but else am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

[MVP Tips](http://www.flounder.com/mvp_tips.htm) is a treasure trove of articles and information that relate to visual c++ and MFC.  There's not much out there beyond codeplex and the Microsoft news groups/forums

Comment: A little bit outdated.

Answer (score 2):

[codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/MFC/) is my favorite web site
There is also an excellent book

[image: MFC answers]

Answer (score 2):

You should also look at the [microsoft.public.vc.mfc](http://www.microsoft.com/communities/newsgroups/list/en-us/default.aspx?dg=microsoft.public.vc.mfc) and [microsoft.public.vc.language](http://www.microsoft.com/communities/newsgroups/list/en-us/default.aspx?dg=microsoft.public.vc.language) newsgroups, and the [Visual C++ General](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vcgeneral/threads/) and [Visual C++ Language](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vclanguage/threads/) forums on MSDN, where there are some highly knowledgeable and helpful people. (It's a shame the MSDN forums aren't better designed - they should take a close look at StackOverflow.)

Comment: The two newsgroups you referred have dead links. Their pages say:


Service Temporarily Unavailable
We apologize for this inconvenience. Please try again later.

Do they still exist?

Answer (score 0):

irc #winprog on efnet